# Bash: Handling Formatting of logfile output

Tags: bash, sed, string-formatting

I have a string formatting problem which, while I know what I want to do, I'm not sure exactly how. I hope somewhere here can help. My problem looks something like this:

In my scripts I use functions to write log output which uses a standardised, but variable length, header and user-defined message body. The length of the message and the terminal width means that messages often wrap around. What I want to do is to insert "padding" in the lines that wrap so that messages appear more formatted in the log.

Here is an adapted and untested extract of part of my working code. It shows what I want to do:

```
local __mgs_hdr="[${__DATE}@${__TIME} ${__script}] -> "
local __msg_body="${1}"
local __hdrlen=$(expr length $__msg_hdr)
local __msglen=$(expr length $__msg_body)
local __max_msglen=$(expr 80 - $__hdrlen)
local __line=""

if [ $__msglen -gt $__max_mslen ]; then # we need to format the message
    # Insert newline followed by "$__hdrlen" whitespaces into $__msq_body at $_hdrlen intervals
    # to align/justify log lines as blocks of text for each log header entry
    # Replace the : with a command to format $__line
    :
else
    __line="${__msg_hdr}${__msg_body}"
fi
```

So, I have an approach for determining when to pad out a log line and I presume sed can do this. I just don't know how. If anyone can point me in the right direction I'll appreciate it.

Here's an example output generated using static formatting. It shows what I'm trying to get to:

```
[2012-12-27@15:56:43 test.sh] -> Writing a log file entry that 
                                 is wrapped onto the next line 
                                 with appropriate formatting...
```

I hope that makes what I'm trying to achieve a little clearer. The line length doesn't match up with an 80 character terminal but the example is illustrative.

Comment: you'd be better off with an example of your input and of your expected output, rather than saying only what you did

Comment: `man printf` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if the script name is_a_really_long_name.sh ?

```
[2012-12-27@15:56:43 is_a_really_long_name.sh] -> Writing a lo
                                                  g file entry 
                                                  that is wrapp
                                                  ed onto the n
                                                  ext line with
                                                  appropriate f
                                                  ormatting...
```

If you care about formatting then why not just have your header on one line and the log message formatted on the lines below it

```
[2012-12-27@15:56:43 is_a_really_long_name.sh] ->
Writing a log file entry that is wrapped onto the next line with appropriate
formatting...
```

---

Some code - the former

```
#!/bin/bash
headerlen=40
maxlinelen=79
linelen=$maxlinelen-headerlen
spaces="                                                                               "
msg="This is a message that needs to be split into chunks that are the same width. For illustrative purpose only. Your milage mag vary."

msglen=${#msg}
start=0
while [ $start -lt  $msglen ]
do
    echo -n "${spaces:1:$headerlen}"
    echo "${msg:$start:$linelen}"
    let start=$start+$linelen
done
```

If you want to do the latter then you can use something like this to split you message up

```
#!/bin/bash

linelen=10

msg="This is a message that needs to be split into chunks that are the same width. For illustrative purpose only. Your milage mag vary."

msglen=${#msg}
start=0
while [ $start -lt  $msglen ]
do
    echo "${msg:$start:$linelen}"
    let start=$start+$linelen
done
```

Comment: I like your `spaces` variable, but it's more a dirty (and breakable) hack than a serious solution. `printf` is much more appropriate. Also, `let` is deprecated, use shell arithmetic instead. Incidentally, shell arithmetic will enable you to write your test in your `while` loop in a much better way. `:-/`

Comment: Yes, I thought about the scenario where the header length is longer than the term width last night. I'll need to handle that - probably by subtracting the term width from the elongated header length.

Comment: @d_w_r: I've spent many years working with log files and to be honest I've never really had an issue with the everything on one line formatting. Your 'pretty' log files though would quickly become irritating as for example I couldn't grep for a particular term and expect to get the whole log entry relating to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that can help you (in bash):

```
print_padded() {
    local header=$1
    local msg=( $2 )
    local width=$3
    local headerlength=${#header}
    local i=0
    local spaceleft=$((width-headerlength))
    local defaultspace=20
    (((spaceleft<0) && (spaceleft=defaultspace)))
    local buf=()
    local s
    printf "%s" "$header"
    while ((i<${#msg[@]})); do
       if ((${#msg[i]}+1<=spaceleft)); then
          printf " %s" "${msg[i]}"
          ((spaceleft-=${#msg[i++]}+1))
       else
          echo
          (((spaceleft=width-headerlength)<0 && (spaceleft=defaultspace)))
          while ((${#msg[i]}>=spaceleft)); do
             (((s=width-${#msg[i]})<0 && (s=0)))
             printf "%${s}s%s\n" '' "${msg[i++]}"
          done
          printf "%${headerlength}s" ''
       fi
    done
    echo
}
```

Then use as, e.g.,

```
$ # Demo with 40 columns...
$ msg="Writing a log file entry that is wrapped onto the next line with appropriate formatting..."
$ print_padded "[2012-12-27@15:56:43 test.sh] ->" "$msg" 40
[2012-12-27@15:56:43 test.sh] -> Writing
                                 a log
                                 file
                                 entry
                                 that is
                                 wrapped
                                 onto
                                 the
                                 next
                                 line
                                 with
                             appropriate
                           formatting...
$ # Demo with 60 columns:
$ loremipsum="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing \
elit. Duis erat purus, vestibulum non sollicitudin ornare, aliquam \
nec mi. In vulputate velit ut felis porta tincidunt. Integer odio \
odio, ullamcorper id ultricies a, fermentum vitae augue. \
Nunc sapien ipsum, dignissim sit amet eleifend eu, suscipit sed eros. \
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi feugiat interdum ligula \
eu consectetur. Sed congue lacinia felis, a adipiscing nibh \
aliquam in. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus \
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin faucibus ultrices tincidunt."
$ print_padded "loremipsum ->" "$loremipsum" 60
loremipsum -> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
              adipiscing elit. Duis erat purus, vestibulum
              non sollicitudin ornare, aliquam nec mi. In
              vulputate velit ut felis porta tincidunt.
              Integer odio odio, ullamcorper id ultricies a,
              fermentum vitae augue. Nunc sapien ipsum,
              dignissim sit amet eleifend eu, suscipit sed
              eros. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi
              feugiat interdum ligula eu consectetur. Sed
              congue lacinia felis, a adipiscing nibh
              aliquam in. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
              faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere
              cubilia Curae; Proin faucibus ultrices
              tincidunt.
```

Now I hope you won't have any formatting junk in your messages (e.g., color codes, etc.), otherwise this script will fail miserably.

It breaks lines wrt to words (at spaces). As you'll see in the first output, if a line is too long to fit, it is put flush right (if possible) on a line of its own.

If you don't care about breaking in the middle of words, it's much easier:

```
print_padded() {
    local header=$1
    local msg=$2
    local width=$3
    local headerlength=${#header}
    local i
    local msgspace=$((width-headerlength))
    (((msgspace<0) && (msgspace=20)))
    printf "%s %s\n" "$header" "${msg:$i:$msgspace}"
    for ((i=msgspace;i<${#msg};i+=msgspace)); do
        printf "%${headerlength}s %s\n" '' "${msg:$i:$msgspace}"
    done
}
```

Then:

```
$ # Demo with 40 columns...
$ msg="Writing a log file entry that is wrapped onto the next line with appropriate formatting..."
$ print_padded "[2012-12-27@15:56:43 test.sh] ->" "$msg" 40
[2012-12-27@15:56:43 test.sh] -> Writing 
                                 a log fi
                                 le entry
                                  that is
                                  wrapped
                                  onto th
                                 e next l
                                 ine with
                                  appropr
                                 iate for
                                 matting.
$ # Demo with 60 columns:
$ loremipsum="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing \
elit. Duis erat purus, vestibulum non sollicitudin ornare, aliquam \
nec mi. In vulputate velit ut felis porta tincidunt. Integer odio \
odio, ullamcorper id ultricies a, fermentum vitae augue. \
Nunc sapien ipsum, dignissim sit amet eleifend eu, suscipit sed eros. \
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi feugiat interdum ligula \
eu consectetur. Sed congue lacinia felis, a adipiscing nibh \
aliquam in. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus \
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin faucibus ultrices tincidunt."
$ print_padded "loremipsum ->" "$loremipsum" 60
loremipsum -> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisc
              ing elit. Duis erat purus, vestibulum non solli
              citudin ornare, aliquam nec mi. In vulputate ve
              lit ut felis porta tincidunt. Integer odio odio
              , ullamcorper id ultricies a, fermentum vitae a
              ugue. Nunc sapien ipsum, dignissim sit amet ele
              ifend eu, suscipit sed eros. In hac habitasse p
              latea dictumst. Morbi feugiat interdum ligula e
              u consectetur. Sed congue lacinia felis, a adip
              iscing nibh aliquam in. Vestibulum ante ipsum p
              rimis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posue
              re cubilia Curae; Proin faucibus ultrices tinci
              dunt.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's very interesing and will map well, with a few mods, to what I've been doing. Thankyou:)